# HP Proliant RAID setup; does the order matter?

Tags: raid, hp

This should be a simple answer but I need to know before proceeding with my configuration.  I have an HP Proliant DL380 G6 6-port server.  I need to create a Raid array using 4 drives but port 1 and 3 are in use so can I create a Raid10 array using ports 2-4-5-6 ?  Or should they be consecutive?  Does it even matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also just move the drives into the ports you prefer...

In one action, you could move the disk in port 3 to port 2.

In a separate action (following a reboot and the controller drive recognition), you could populate the remaining drive slots.

But if not, no, it doesn't matter. You The array controller doesn't require the drives to be in any specific order.

It sounds like you're trying to do something where you're splitting OS disks from data drives. If you're using the same size disks across the array, you may be better served by making a large RAID 1+0 and creating [multiple HP *Logical Drives*](https://serverfault.com/questions/272787/how-can-i-speed-up-the-build-of-a-logical-drive-on-a-hp-smart-array-p411/272802#272802). It's an option to consider.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  That's exactly what I needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

For ease of management, having RAID sets span consecutive bays is probably better, but there's no *technical* reason why they have to be.